# cal command - start monday

Tags: mac, terminal, calendar

I was wondering - is there a way to make 'cal' (a terminal program) start the week on monday?

Usually it can be done with the -m flag, but this does not have any effect on the Mac. AFAIK, for freebsd you need deskutils, but I could not find any equivalent on the mac, even in homebrew.

Is there a switch or alternate source for a cal tool that allows weekday start changes?

Answer (score 26):

[GNU cal](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/gcal.html) has a `--starting-day` option:

```
$ brew install gcal
$ alias cal='gcal --starting-day=1'
$ cal

      June 2013
 Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                 1  2
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

`ncal` also starts weeks on mondays by default:

```
$ ncal
    June 2013
Mo     3 10 17 24
Tu     4 11 18 25
We     5 12 19 26
Th     6 13 20 27
Fr     7 14 21 28
Sa  1  8 15 22 29
Su  2  9 16 23 30
```

Answer (score 8):

[This Macworld.com OS X Hint](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040625094428394) shows some scripting to put Monday first…

```
cal | awk '{ print " "$0; getline; print " Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su"; \
getline; if (substr($0,1,2) == " 1") print "                    1 "; \
do { prevline=$0; if (getline == 0) exit; print " " \
substr(prevline,4,17) " " substr($0,1,2) " "; } while (1) }'
```

Result:

```
      June 2013
 Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
                 1  2 
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Comment: this is really ugly but cool ! :-)

Answer (score 3):

`$ man cal` says: *"The cal utility displays a simple calendar in traditional format and ncal offers an alternative layout, more options and the date of easter. The new format is a little cramped but it makes a year fit on a 25x80 terminal. If arguments are not specified, the current month is displayed"*. To me, it seems preferable to use `ncal` as opposed to implementing an ugly hack.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to install the same Linux version that comes with `-m` option for Mac through Homebrew, under the package `util-linux`.

```sh
$ brew install util-linux
```

It will be installed under `/usr/local/opt/util-linux/bin`.

```
$ /usr/local/opt/util-linux/bin/cal -m
     April 2022     
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
```

However *it won't be automatically added to the PATH by Homebrew*. You will have to do this manually or use an alias.